# Opening a standlone application upon submit button click

Tags: javascript, java, server, desktop-application

I am developing an application with the following requirements.

When you click on the submit button in the web-page, it should open a standalone application(Example : like a calculator in windows).

Is there a possibility to deploy an already built standalone application into a server and get the url, so that i can use `assign()` or `replace()` of java script method in the submit button and redirect to that url?

Comment: No, this cannot be done. At most, you can try to open a specific file, e.g., `.doc` which will prompt the browser to resolve how to open it. By default most browsers will ask the user ("Do you want to open in Word?", "Do you want to download?") but they might also be configured to straight use an application. However all of that is outside of your control, you cannot _demand_ a browser opens any other application, you can merely _suggest_ that the datatype you are sending is X and that's it - whether it will be opened using Y or Z is outside of your control.

Comment: Hi Vlaz, Thank u very much for the reply. did not get exact meaning of below lines. 'which will prompt the browser to resolve how to open it. ' and as you mentioned 'you can try to open a specific file, e.g., .doc', is that possible to open Microsoft word on click of submit button? how?

Comment: It's not possible for you to open Word. The _browser_ may decide to open it but that would still ultimately depend on the user's choice and environment. There is no way to force that decision nor can you even suggest which exact application would be opened. If you give the user a PDF, then the browser may open it in a PDF reader but it doesn't need to be Adobe Acrobat. It may even decide to open it in an unrelated application, or not to open it at all. At any rate, the choice is out of your hands.